# How to give variable names to variables? c#

Tags: c#, class, variables

Well, my problems is the following, I have a class named player, and I want to generate n objects whose name are  "myPlayerN" where N is the number of the object, so I can use them later for diferent purposes. This better explained would be something like:

```
int numplayers=n;
for(i=0;i<numplayers;i++)
  {
    player myPlayer+numplayers = new player();
  }
```

Comment: instead of creating a different name, have an `ID` field in player, assign that the unique number. Since you are dealing with a collection of objects, add that to a container like `List<player>`

Comment: Even if you could do this, those variables would be gone once you exited the loop scope. You probably want to stick them into a collection so you can use them later...

Comment: You really don't want to do this with fancy names(even if you could somehow). Use an array or collection instead... so myPlayerN = myPlayer[N].

Comment: Expanding on @Habib's comments, if you need to access Players by their ID, you might also look into using `Dictionary<int, player>` (assuming the ID is an int type).

Comment: You should follow the .NET convention of making type names PascalCase, so `Player` instead of `player`, and local variables camelCase, so `numPlayers`.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for an `array`.

```
var players = new player[numplayers];

for(int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
     players[i] = new player();
```

Shorter way:

```
var players = Enumerable.Range(0, numplayers)
              .Select(x => new player()).ToArray();
```

After that you can access your players using an index (e.g. `players[2]`).Remember that array indices are *zero-based*, so the first element of your array is `players[0]` not `players[1]`.Refer to the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for detailed information about arrays.

Further reading

- [Arrays Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: This Q+A brought back memories! I remember discovering about arrays when I was starting out. First real 'wow' moment.

Comment: oh dear.... I think maybe you should read a book to get the "Basics". If we help you with this yr just get stuck at the next simple thing. Read a book!

Comment: @Joe you'r right, I have added a link to Arrays Tutorial on msdn since it's a too broad subject that I can't explain in one answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need either an array or a list. Since you probably don't know, in advance, how many you will need, I suggest a list:

```
List<player> players = new List<player>();

var p = new player();
players.Add(p);
```

Comment: @jumpingcode That doesn't make a list the wrong choice.  Arrays really have very few advantages over lists in general.

Comment: I'd include the caveat that you should initialize the list with an initial capacity if you know it, but @Servy's point is sound - the overhead of using a `List<T>` instead of an array is incredibly small.

Comment: Oh no, I agree, I wasn't saying it was wrong. I'd almost always prefer to use `List<T>`

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Unless the initial capacity is *really* large, there's not a particularly compelling reason to even do that.  It's not really *wrong* to do so, but unless you're at the point where you have hundreds of thousands, or millions, of items, it's a micro optimization.  Not wrong, but likely not wrong if you don't do it either.